# Supporting DPI and Default Font Changes

Tags: .net, winforms, dpi, highdpi

So I'm trying to figure out how the Form's AutoScaleMode property can possibly help to support a system with a font or [DPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) that is different from my work development machine.

From the SDK:

> AutoScaleMode Enumeration
>
> public enum AutoScaleMode
>
> ```
> None  
>    Automatic scaling is disabled.    
> Font   
>    Controls scale relative to the dimensions of the 
>    font the classes are using, which is typically the 
>    system font.
> Dpi    
>    Controls scale relative to the display resolution. 
>    Common resolutions are 96 and 120 DPI.
> ```

By default .NET 2.0 Forms use AutoScaleMode.Font.

So I designed a sample form on my Windows XP, Tahoma 8 pt, 96 DPI development machine. Then I tried it out on a

- 14 pt Segoe UI 96 DPI machine
- 14 pt Segoe UI 150 DPI machine

The results were not encouraging, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

The AutoScaleMode property was not designed to enable a .NET Form for support of different font or DPI settings. So what **is** the proper way to support different font and DPI settings?

Answer (score 6):

The correct way is to scale the controls, the form itself and the text within. This sounds very complicated, but the layout controls (TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayoutPanel), combined with the AutoSize property, make this considerably less difficult.

Comment: Layout panels wouldn't be of any use in the above form, things already are layed out using anchors.

Comment: Replace the anchors. The anchors are the issue.

Comment: Replace them with what? The button is 50dlus wide, and is 7dlus from the right and bottom edge.

Comment: Replace the entire layout with a TableLayout or FlowLayout, and re-layout the form on said Layout control, using it to handle all your scaling dirty work. Anchors are great for keeping a control in a given position, they do not inherently provide you nice scaling.

Comment: @romkyns: Thanks for the note; I thought I cleaned those all up. Removing the link.